# conda build and conda install using different version of the same dependencies, why?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

in our CI process we do the following things:

1. create a whole new conda enviorment for this CI pipeline
2. create a conda package using `conda build`, the output folder is set to ./build
3. install the newly created package using `conda install -c ./build package_name`.

Second step is so in our second stage of the CI, when we are testing, we just invoke pytest to run all the test files in the CI environment and using the newly installed `package_name` package.

Note `package_name` has a internal dependency `another_package_name` listed in the meta.yaml file which defines the package.

One thing we have found is that in step 1 and step 2, the version of `another_package_name` is different, when building the package, conda seems to be able to get the latest version of the dependency. At step 2 though, conda seems to be picking an old version of the dependency.

Some other findings I have:

1. Both `package_name` and `another_package_name` is published to a file location we use for our internal channel (using plain `cp *.tar.bz2` command)
2. This is only happening in the CI, to the particular CI user, and only happening if we are in that CI folder and in that CI environment, meaning using a different user, creating a new environment, copying the `./build` folder out to somewhere else all stop us from reproducing this behavior.

This is blocking us to have a proper functional CI. And we could not find out what's going on with the `local install` step and why does it picks the wrong version of the dependency.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong, but you might fix the problem (or perhaps get some useful error message output) by specifying the newer version of `another_package_name` in step 3. `conda install -c ./build package_name another_package_name=0.0.0`

Comment: Is it possible that `another_package_name` is present in `./build`?

Comment: @darthbith I checked it is not

Comment: Is there a `.condarc` file somewhere inside this user's folder? If yes, what are the contents of this file?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo yep there is, it has the channels to our custom conda channels.

Comment: Do other (unaffected) user accounts also have the same `.condarc` file? I'd start by checking this.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo no they don't share the same .condarc, but the only thing changed is the order of the channels. I have carefully checked and find the order only affect this particular user.

Comment: Have you tried using the exact same `.condarc` (with the same order of channels)?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I tried. The channel order only affects this user but not other users.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem, by including the `--update-specs` option in my `conda install ...` command.

Any luck?

For the record, my exact problem was that the dependency version requirements of a `conda` package installed in "develop" mode were not being respected without this option.